# Remove all lines does not contain email in bash

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I have file 100MB  with so many email and i want to delete lines not contain a emails with bash shell
how do I do this with bash shell?
exmple

```
BR,"",adriano-piassali,adriano piassali,""
"conceicao, sao paulo, BR","",adriano-name,name,""
"sorocaba, sao paulo, BR","",adriano-name,name,""
"BS, massachusetts, US","",adriano-name,name piris
"johannesburg, gauteng, ST","",adriano-name,name ,""
"ponta kak, name, BR","email@exmple.com",adriano-name,name,""
"BL, emilia-name, IT","",adriano-name,name,""
US,"",adriano-name-name,adriano name,""
```

i want just take

```
"ponta kak, parana, BR","email@exmple.com",adriano-premebida,adriano,""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `grep` with an email regex:

```
grep -Ei '([[:alnum:]_.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,})' filenamehere
```

Comment: I would remove the `6` in the regex. This assumes that the final part of the domain is no longer than 6 characters. What about the domain `.amsterdam`, `.services`, `.software` etc.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I've removed it.